# OSX -- Output WAV independently to 12 speakers connected via USB soundcards

Tags: macos, audio, playback, simultaneous, speaker

I wish to simultaneously play sounds through up to 12 mono speakers.

I could connect these to my MacBook using 6 USB soundcards, and use the left and right channel of each.

But how can I get the MacBook to play sound out of speaker #5, for example?

PS If anyone can see a smarter way to wire up 12 speakers to a MacBook, please do say!

Comment: Same sounds? Or are you trying to send discrete sound information to each speaker programmatically?

Comment: I believe the Audio MIDI Setup utility in /Applications/Utilities should help you set up such an *Aggregate-Audio-Device*. But this question is more suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @gaige: Separate sounds!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.   I was going to suggest the Audio MIDI Setup utility for ganging speakers together for the same sounds (as @deceze did above), but for separate sounds, you're going to want to look at the MIDI Manager and AV Foundation.  You might want to start looking at the `settings` property and the `AVChannelLayoutKey` option for specifying a particular output channel.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup an `Aggregate Device` (Audio Midi Setup > Create Aggregate Device), which allows the ability to combine multiple devices of the same model, or to combine multiple inputs and outputs for apps that don't support separate input and output devices. [This Apple guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3956) shows how it works and is surprisingly quite easy to setup.

Another way to route audio to multiple channels and outputs (up to 64) is with the free app/plug-in [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/). You can download a [compiled version](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/downloads/list), or compile the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/source/browse/#svn/trunk) if you want/need to specifically do something that the current compiled version might not.